# PowerShell: Duplicate windows forms with different properties

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am trying make copies of windows forms objects and change the properties of new objects. For example:

```
$List1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$List1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$List1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,310)

$List2 = $List1
$List2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,10)
```

The problem is that `$List2` is a pointer of `$List1`. Whatever I change on `$List2` always change the properties on `$List1`. Is there a solution for this?

```
$List1.Location

IsEmpty   X  Y
-------   -  -
  False 350 10



$List1.Location

IsEmpty   X  Y
-------   -  -
  False 350 10
```

Answer (score 4):

> Whatever I change on $List2 always change the properties on $List1. Is there a solution for this?

Yes, the solution is to create a new instance of `ListBox`:

```
$List1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$List1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$List1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,310)

$List2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$List2.Size = $List1.Size
$List2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,10)
```

Notice that `$List2.Size = $List1.Size` is safe, because `Size` is a struct, and structs are copied on assignment

---

If you have many properties to reference, you could wrap the common property values in a hashtable to pass to `New-Object -Property`:

```
$ListBoxDefaultProperties = @{
    Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (10,10)
    Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (280,310)
    BackColor = 'Beige'
    DisplayMember = 'SomePropertyName'
    # etc...
}
$List1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox -Property $ListBoxDefaultProperties
$List2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox -Property $ListBoxDefaultProperties
$List3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox -Property $ListBoxDefaultProperties
```

Comment: I have set over 15 custom properties of $List1. Creating new objects and writing same code over and over... it's just a waste.

Comment: @LethalHologram That's what loops are for.

Comment: Is it possible to add event into the hash table? I mean This:

$List.Add_TextChanged({
 $List.SelectionStart = $List.Text.Length; 
 $List.ScrollToCaret()
})

Comment: @Vinkelman I'd suggest you post that as a separate question, comments are not really fit for that

Answer (score 0):

`$List1` and `$List2` reference the *same* object because you did `$List1 = $List2`.

You have to create 2 separate instances. You can set all common properties in a loop and then only change the properties that differ:

```
# 1. create two separate instances
$list1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$list2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

# 2. set properties on both instances
foreach ($list in ($list1, $list2)) {
    $list.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 10)
    $list.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280, 310)
    # [...]
}

# 3. set all different properties on the 2nd instance only
$list2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 10)
# [...]
```